# Calculate and return a single distance value between matrices A and B in R

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I have seen similar post about distances (mostly euclidean) between matrices A and B. However they return a matrix of the distance between each matched observations (Row).

Now I have this problem, say I have a list of drug treatments, each treatment is a list containing a matrix of N rows x 9 columns. So each treatment list have different rows (experiment subjects) but all the same columns (variables).

I want to compare how similar the treatments are based on how the same experiment subject responded to the treatment according to the measured variables. SO it came to me to see if I can compute the distance between each treatment matrix and return a single value, then I can that value in a matrix that contains all the comparison between the treatments. Finally I can visualize the relationship of treatments in a heatmap by hierarchical clustering.

```
 #take 2 treatments as an example:
 set.seed(123)
 Treatment1 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:10000,3), 
               y=sample(1:10000,3), 
               z=sample(1:10000,3))
 Treatment2 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100,3), 
               y=sample(1:100,3), 
               z=sample(1:1000,3))

 #lets say I have 10 treatments/drugs aka length(Drugs)= 10
 Drugs <- list(Treatment1,Treatment2,...Treatment10 )

 #load an empty matrix to record all distances
 distance <- matrix(1, nrow = length(Drugs), ncol = length(Drugs))

 #now I want to construct the matrix of all the distance measurements:

 for (i in 1:(length(Drugs) - 1)){
  for (j in (i+1):length(Drugs)){
  # Match by ID, lets assume the 1st column is the ID
  total <- inner_join(Drugs[[i]], Drugs[[j]], by = c("ID"))
  # Calculate distance and store 
  distance <- #some sort of dist function(total[,drugi], total[,drugj])

  # Store in correct location on matrix
  distance_values[i,j] <- distance 
  distance_values[j,i] <- distance 

  plot(hclust(distance))
```

So I got stuck at the #some sort of dist function, to me all distmap, pdist functions returns a matrix between row observations between 2 matrices hence I can't load a matrix into a single position of my empty matrix. I need a single number between any given matrices. Am I making sense? What function could I use to calculate such distance ?

Comment: I don't think this approach makes much sense.  It seems to me you have a bunch of treatments, a bunch of subjects, and a bunch of outcome variables, which happen to be split into chunks. Why not just bind your list elements into one big data frame and run a multivariate analysis? You can't meaningfully talk about distances between matrices unless your outcome measures are all on the same scale and in the same units, in which case maybe `sqrt(sum((matrix2-matrix1)^2))` might work as a single distance measurement, but I think there are better ways to handle this problem.

Comment: Dear @AllanCameron, thank you for your response man. Yes you are right, the first "single number" that came to my mind was using coefficient. But the result showing the drug similarities has some issues: some known similar drugs aren't similar from this result. So I want to try another method. You are correct that I have a bunch of treatments, but all most all subjects are the same and the outcomes are the same(scale and units, because they are classification results, aka 30 cells in a bin(variable column)).

Comment: @AllanCameron Sorry that  I'm quite stupid in statistics. so what kind of multivariate analysis are we talk about here so I can have a read on? In the mean time, I think the  sqrt(sum((matrix2-matrix1)^2)) approach actually sounds okay. How do I implement it? literally just pass my treatment in the formula?